# org.restlet.ext.crypto not in Restlet Maven Repo

Tags: gwt, restlet

I cannot find the org.restlet.ext.crypto package in the Restlet maven repo http://maven.restlet.org/

Strange that the examples use it though its nowhere to be found in the maven repo.

Anyone know why this is or have a similar experience. I am trying to fit Restlet into an existing GWT project using maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvermind I found it. They don't have it under the gwt dir. It's under the other editions, Java EE, Java SE etc